# How can I use a dictionary to implement "switch/case", where evaluating the values could fail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am working on the following problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5266876b8f4bf2da9b000362/train/python

> Implement a function likes :: [String] -> String, which must take in
> input array, containing the names of people who like an item. It must
> return the display text as shown in the examples:
>
> ```
> likes([]) # must be "no one likes this"
> likes(["Peter"]) # must be "Peter likes this"
> likes(["Jacob", "Alex"]) # must be "Jacob and Alex like this"
> likes(["Max", "John", "Mark"]) # must be "Max, John and Mark like this"
> likes(["Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max"]) # must be "Alex, Jacob and 2 others like this"
> ```

Here is my solution:

```
def likes(names):
    length = len(names)
    switcher = {
        0: "no one likes this",
        1: f"{names} likes this", 
        2: f'{names[0]} and {names[1]} like this', 
        3: f'{names[0]}, {names[1]} and {names[2]} like this', 
        4: f'{names[0]}, {names[1]} and ({length} - 2) others like this'
    }
    return switcher.get(length)
```

But if I call it with a list containing fewer than 2 names, I get the IndexError:

```
2: f'{names[0]} and {names[1]} like this',
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why can't I do it this way or if I can how do I get around this?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.  Your posted code defines a function and quits without getting called.

Comment: You've answered your question yourself, you can't access a list element that doesn't exist

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> length = len(names)
> switcher = {
>     0: "no one likes this",
>     1: f"{names} likes this", 
>     2: f'{names[0]} and {names[1]} like this', 
>     3: f'{names[0]}, {names[1]} and {names[2]} like this', 
>     4: f'{names[0]}, {names[1]} and ({length} - 2) others like this'
> }
> return switcher.get(length)
> ```

Here, presumably you were expecting that this behaves like a chained `if`/`elif` statement like this:

```
if length == 0:
    return "no one likes this"
elif length == 1:
    return f"{names} likes this"
elif length == 2:
    return f'{names[0]} and {names[1]} like this'
```

and so on, where each return expression is only evaluated if the corresponding condition is true.

But that is not the case. The dictionary `switcher` is built completely *before* the `length` comes into play. So when passing a list `names` with less than 2 elements, the values for 2, 3, and 4 elements are still evaluated, which raises an `IndexError`, since `names[1]`, or even `names[0]` do not exist.

The clearest way around this is just using `if`/`elif`/`else`.

---

You *could* create a dictionary containing *functions* which in turn return the formatted strings.

The "else" case should not be in the `4` key, but corresponds to the default value returned by `.get()`:

```
def likes(names):
    length = len(names)
    switcher = {
        0: lambda _: "no one likes this",
        1: lambda n: f"{n[0]} likes this", 
        2: lambda n: f'{n[0]} and {n[1]} like this', 
        3: lambda n: f'{n[0]}, {n[1]} and {n[2]} like this'
    }
    formatter = switcher.get(
        length,
        lambda n: f'{n[0]}, {n[1]} and ({length} - 2) others like this'
    )
    return formatter(names)
```

<sub>Note that in the `1` case you should use `names[0]`, not `names`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the dictionary tries to create all its elements when you define `switcher`, and fails when `lenght <= 2` since the third element (`names[2]`) does not exist and thus, it raises an error